# Reading last few lines of a log file, with a twist

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I trying to read the last 50-70 lines of a log file, the log files can get VERY large and so i need some way to only get the last lines and not download the whole file.

This is because the file is going to be streamed to users, so they can see their servers in real-time.

I am planning on using jQuery to update the UI and PHP to download the log and sort it into lines.

If this way of doing it is stupid, please advise something else.

To top things off, the twist, all the log files are remote and have to be accessed via FTP, with authentication. That rules out fseek :(

Thanks!

Comment: Only a server side solution, the file should be requested via FTP protocol and having a file partially download would work, but you would only get the start of the log?

Comment: Is there any way to get SSH access instead of FTP? You could have a script on the server that would send back the output of running tail on the log.

Comment: Hi Yes, i have SSH2 libs, however, it would be requesting the files every 2 seconds, wouldn't this be slow?

Comment: Okay so at the minute, i have an SSH2 connection, using this; $command = "tail -70 $myfile"; It returns it fine, just wondering whether this would be a strain on system resources?

Comment: I don't think that will be too much of a strain, if you're only doing this once every couple seconds total (not once every couple seconds per site visitor).

Answer (score 1):

I could only think of some kind of service on the remote site, that gives you the part that you want.

Or, you could use something like [rsync](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html), and keep your local copy in sync with the remote one. Rsync is very clever with block transfers, so your local file could be very frequent updated.

Both solutions are not FTP however.

Comment: +1 for rsync, it would seem that it is a fairly standard protocol for these kinds of operations today :)